# How to facebook user's information

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cakephp

I am using facebook graph. I am able to retrieve the access_token. Now I want to get info using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX/?access_token=111978178853984|2.1lD7XrS1n7C3UgudmiSpQg__.3600.1279976400-10000XXXXXXXXX|9vJZuRDvlzLhFfGkqGkg92KmDSE.
```

I already multiple ways to retrieve json output.

1) jquery.getJSON method - Falied due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol

2) tried file_get_contents method - Falied again - Unfortunately I am using shared server, file_get_contents is not allowed.

3) tried httpSocket method - failed - I get output as null.

I am running out ideas to get it work. I am not familiar with cURL.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)/[`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) but you need to make a slight addition to the URL by [adding `&callback=?` on there](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp), like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX/?access_token=111978178853984|2.1lD7XrS1n7C3UgudmiSpQg__.3600.1279976400-10000XXXXXXXXX|9vJZuRDvlzLhFfGkqGkg92KmDSE&callback=?
```

Then just use that url:

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX/?access_token=111978178853984|2.1lD7XrS1n7C3UgudmiSpQg__.3600.1279976400-10000XXXXXXXXX|9vJZuRDvlzLhFfGkqGkg92KmDSE&callback=?', function(data) {
  //use data, it's a json object
});
```

This will request the content in a different way, using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) which will get around the same-origin policy ([and facebook supports this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript)).

Answer (score 0):

Try using either the official Facebook [PHP SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), or the [JavaScript SDK](http://github.com/facebook/connect-js).